# MTM Installation without Visual studio

Tags: installation

Is it possible to install MTM without installing the Visual Studio?Whether a stand alone MTM is possible? If yes please mention how to install MTM without Visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to separately buy Test Professional. That's about the only way to do it. Very frustrating.